# Custom iOS keyboard works in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I have created Keyboard extension for stickers. It works fine in simulator but when i try to run in real device it won't work. It gives following error[image: plugin interrupted]

Please help me I've been trying to fix it since 2 days.

Comment: Changed question from vague ('not working') to stating the real problem: discrepancy between behavior in the Simulator and on an actual device.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: did you resolved it ? I'm also facing same issue now